# How can I select the previous html element of the last element that have the same class and the same type in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

if I have this code

```
<div id="someId">
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <div class="example"></div>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">another example</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If I don't know the number of select elements and I need to get the previous select element of the last select element value
how can I do this using jquery
can anyone help me with this please

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Does that mean the value of the second-to-last `<select>` element?

Comment: @showdev - yes I ment that

Comment: If you ask next time a question be more specific, You asked in title " last element that have the SAME CLASS and the SAME TYPE" and accepted the answer without getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**:eq()**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20eq%20selector)

```
var selectLength = $('select').length;
var secondToLast = $('select:eq('+(selectLength-2)+')');
```

or

```
var secondToLast = $('select:eq(-2)');
```

```js
var selectLength = $('select').length;
var secondToLast = $('select:eq(' + (selectLength - 2) + ')');

console.log(secondToLast);
secondToLast = $('select:eq(' + (selectLength - 2) + ')');


console.log(secondToLast);

secondToLast.css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someId">
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">some example</option>
  </select>
  <select class="example">
    <option value="1">another example</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Incidentally, your second method doesn't need the length calculation.

Comment: @ammarCSE - This is working .. thank you very much for helping me

Comment: @showdev, the evils of copy pasting(your own stuff). Thanks for the tip! :)